# change legend labels of geom_tile to log10 format

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, heatmap

how can i change label in heatmap to log10 format? like `c(10^-4.5, 10^-4, 10^-3.5, 10^-3)`

i have tried but didn't work, says NAs produced

```
myGGplotObject + scale_fill_gradient(name = "log10(meaurement of interest)",low="white", high="red",
breaks = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(expr = 10^.x)),
labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(expr = 10^.x))
)
```

here's a full example of my code

```
# load Library
library(tidyverse)


# create example dataSet
x <- LETTERS[1:20]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,20))
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
length_measurement <- 400
data$Z <- rnorm(400, 0.000025, 0.0005)

#add NA's 
addNA <- sample(seq_len(length_measurement), length_measurement/3)
data$Z[addNA] <- NA



#plot Heat map
ggplot(data, aes(Y,X, fill= log10(Z))) + 
  geom_tile() +   scale_fill_gradient(name = "log10(meaurement of interest)",low="white", high="red"#,
                                        #breaks = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(expr = 10^.x)),
                                        #labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(expr = 10^.x))
)
```

Comment: 1) That's not an error, it's a warning; 2) how can you log negative numbers?

Comment: 3) You can pipe the data through `data %>% filter(Z > 0) %>% ggplot(aes(etc))` to get rid of the warning but I believe that you should instead rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: The logarithm function is undefined for negative numbers and produces NaN (Not a Number) in R.

Answer (score 1):

One option to get your labels would be to use `scales::label_math`:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

ggplot(data, aes(Y, X, fill = log10(Z))) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    name = "log10(meaurement of interest)", low = "white", high = "red",
    labels = scales::label_math()
  )
```

[image]